# Can't find "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I just added the `google-play-services-lib` library to my project and am stuck where I need to "sync the project with gradle files", but this button does not exist on IntelliJ 13.0.1. Is there an alternative to this function?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As alternative you can use `Refresh all Gradle projects` button in Gradle tool window.

I also have not found this button so I made my own :)

1. Open Gradle tool window with `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`
2. Start Macro Recording with `Edit -> Macros -> Start Recording Macro`
3. In Gradle tool window press `Refresh all Gradle projects` button
4. Stop Macro Recording with `Edit -> Macros -> Stop Recording Macro`
5. Save Macro with name `Gradle sync`
6. Press with right mouse button on IntelliJ IDEA toolbar and choose `Customize Menus and Toolbars...`
7. Under `Main menu -> Edit -> Macros -> Macro Actions` find your `Gradle sync` Macro, select it and press `Edit Action Icon...`
8. Download this icon [Sync Project With Gradle Files icon](http://developer.android.com/images/tools/sync-project.png) (from documentation http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) and select this icon in IDEA dialog window
9. Now in `Menus and Toolbars` select last item in `Main Toolbar` group, press `Add After...` and select `All actions -> Macros -> Gradle sync`
10. Now you have `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button!

Answer (score 36):

There is a useful shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, after which a window appears and you can type some command that you would like IntelliJ to run. Just type "sync" in there and it will find that command **Sync Project with Gradle Files**, even if it's not visible in the menu.

Answer (score 7):

"Sync Project with Gradle Files" is not present in IntelliJ. However a similar option is available to build all the gradle files together. Go to View --> Tool Windows --> Gradle. A Gradle task panel gets displayed in the right side with the list of apps. Select your app and click the "Refresh all Gradle projects" in the top bar of the Gradle task panel.

Another method is as mentioned by "Avi Arro"

Comment: Only one working solution!

Answer (score 3):

The Gradle sync is still there, under Tools -> Android -> Sync with Gradle

If you don't see it, then Intellij needs to re-link your gradle file.

Try closing the project, re-opening by File -> Import Project -> and select your .gradle file

Comment: Are you sure your version is the latest (13.0.1 ) Because it's not on mine.

Comment: Yes. Did you try importing your project again?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, since the gradle plugin changed a lot in intellij 13, it requires a re-import of the gradle file and then everything is fixed.

Comment: If i close the project, the only way to re-open/import it is from the `Quick Start` column.Is this what you mean.Because that's where i tried to import it from.

Comment: Yes thats right. Honestly I dont know why it doesnt work for you because that's all I had to do

Comment: Beats me too.Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

In my Case, One of My plugin, Android support got disabled due to some reason , As soon as I enabled it , and sync it the button automatically showed.

Go to File > Settings > Plugin > Android support(Tick this).

and sync your project.

Answer (score 1):

I haven`t seen such option in pure IntelliJ. I guess you are developing some android app. You should then switch to Android Studio (based on IntelliJ) where this option is available for sure.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Then why are you asking about how to do things in IntelliJ?

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone who uses Android studio is experiencing this issue (can't find sync gradle feature), I'm posting my answer here. I'm new to Android, so I had no idea to fix this. What I did was I cleared the AS cache.

```
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Voila! The Gradle sync button is now there.