# Where is a "Sync project with gradle files" button in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

This button disappeared from a new 3.1 version of AS Toolbar. Before it showed as:
[image]

Now it's missing:

[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually

Comment: Here is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/q/20815998/6533853

Comment: Is it only the button disappeared or entire Bar?

Comment: @Shailesh, thanks, but amusingly `Tools > Android` also disappeared.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In **Android Studio 3.3** it is here:

[image]

Answer (score 55):

**EDIT**: They like to keep playing with the toolbar.

Since Android Studio 3.3, the icon has been updated and moved back across to the right:

[image]

---

Original answer:

It hasn't disappeared. They have just moved it between the Save and Sync files button on the far left end of the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: It's not there anymore!  They've been playing again!

Comment: Is there any such button for flutter project ??  As of now i'm running 'flutter pub get' from tools->flutter

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy, see below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64119176/2914140.

Comment: I didn't see the button too (Android Studio 2022 Giraffe), and after restarting the IDE (and maybe waiting a couple of minutes too) I suddenly saw it

Answer (score 16):

Is is available from menu. `Tools > Android` disappeared, so find it in `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

[image]

Comment: It's not there anymore.

Comment: @PeteAlvin, I have AS 3.5.1 and menu item is still there (with another icon).

Answer (score 11):

For me I did following to make it visible:

1. Go to File -> settings -> Menus and Tool bar as shown 
   [image: here]
2. Click on Restore Default

You should see the Updated Android.MainToolBarGradleGroup as follows:
[image: Updated Menu]

3. Click on Apply and restart the Android Studio

Comment: Those buttons, like Restore Default, don't appear on my screen.

Comment: when i select it, the apply button does't enable. I guess that means I already have it but i still dont see it.

Answer (score 11):

If you encounter this issue within a Flutter project and you cannot find the sync method, you can click on the build.gradle file and then click on Open for Editing with Android Studio at the top right. This will open just the Android project in a new Android Studio window and you will be able to see all the Gradle commands then (for example, under File > Sync...).

Comment: Add a snapshot pls

Comment: right click on `android/build.gradle` click on **Flutter>Open for Editing with Android Studio** and then you will see the *Sync Project With Gradle Files* icon

Comment: It'll download a lot of Gradle stuff before that though, in the background...

Answer (score 6):

File > Sync Project With Gradle Files or this shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Working in Android 3.6.1

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating React Native application, make sure that you opened your project in `~/YourProjectName/android` folder

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 4):

I had to open **/android/** on its own in Android Studio (you can click Open for Editing in Android Studio in the top right corner) and then you have this options in the toolbar and in File/Synch Project with Gradle Files (when viewing .gradle file).

[image]

Comment: Could you attach screnshots, please? I didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks, hope, it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to get not only sync but also other action if you found trouble to get them.A window will appear and you can type some command that you would like IntelliJ to run. Just type "sync" in there and it will find that command **Sync Project with Gradle Files**, even if it's not visible on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio under 3.1 it's placed in

> Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Is it Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA? Or is it a version before 3.1?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android Studio 3.0 still

Comment: @Acune, unbelievable. :)

Comment: @CoolMind dude, it was three years ago :)