# Where is the "Sync Now" button in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following this Tensorflow [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#4). At the bottom, it says *click Sync Now*. What exactly is that?

Comment: https://www.codingdemos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/android-studio-sync-gradle-file.png

Comment: Very good. Many thanks good sir

Comment: You can also look at the the top toolbar, 4th button from the right (Gradle elephant with a little blue arrow).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575686/where-is-a-sync-project-with-gradle-files-button-in-android-studio-3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually/49576527#49576527 (AS version 3).

Answer (score 11):

It's the "Sync Project with Gradle Files". And you can press it manually whenever you want.

Generally you want to do it when you change some configs in your Gradle Files like adding dependencies, changed signing configs, change version code, etc.

[image]

Comment: this answer should be marked as the best one

Answer (score 4):

In 2021 the name of the pption has changes to " Reload All from Disk" in the File dropdown menu ( same as ctrl+alt+y )

Answer (score 3):

press Ctrl+Alt+y 
to Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 3):

You can use File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files to sync the project manually.