# Can't find the Sync with Gradle button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

today I encountered a problem when trying to run an app from Android Studio. I found out that the solution to the problem is to Sync with Gradle. However, I can't find the Sync with Gradle button in my editor. (None of the solutions listed on StackOverflow worked for me). Here is an image:

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]
[image: File Menu]

### Edit:

I solved this issue by installing Gradle manually.

Comment: It's in the File menu

Comment: I don't have that option in the file menu. I added a new image, you can check it out.

Comment: What version of Android Studio you use?

Comment: I download the latest version from the official site.

Comment: Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575686/where-is-a-sync-project-with-gradle-files-button-in-android-studio-3#:~:text=Is%20is%20available%20from%20menu,Sync%20Project%20with%20Gradle%20Files%20.&text=File%20%3E%20Sync%20Project%20With%20Gradle%20Files%20or%20this%20shortcut.&text=You%20can%20use%20this%20shortcut,found%20trouble%20to%20get%20them. I think you can find there an answer to your issue.

Comment: Hi, I just installed Gradle manually and I have the button in my File Menu just like you said. If you want to you can answer this question and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `File` menu, there you will find the option to Sync Project with Gradle,
Check the image below :

[image: Gradle sync project]

**EDIT**

Goto Settings in `File` Menu as shown in the image below.

[image]

then specify the path of the Gradle File which you have Downloaded Manually & Apply the Settings as shown in the image below.

[image]

After Specifying the path, you see the option "Sync Project With Gradle Files" in File Menu.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I don't have that option in the file menu, I added a new image so you can check it out.

Comment: @Andrej try updating to Android Studio 4.1 (`Help` menu then `Check for updates`)

Comment: Hi, I manually installed Gradle and now I have the Sync with Gradle button on my File Menu. If you want you can write an answer to this question and I will mark it as the correct one.